# Extending the functionalities on a DTO

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DTO as follows.

```
public class PersonDTO
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Assuming I have got a requirement to implement the following interface in the PersonDTO.

```
public Interface ImplementPerson<T>() 
{
  int GetName();
}
```

I do not want to make changes to PersonDTO except inheriting ImplementPerson, what options I have to implement `GetName` method? Finally, when I create an object of PersonDTO I should be able to have GetName() in the intellisense.

```
public class PersonDTO : ImplementPerson<PersonDTO>
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to implement an interface, or do you want to have GetName() available on PersonDTO regardless of how it gets there?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek:I want to have GetName() available on PersonDTO regardless of how it gets there

Comment: Then the best way I know of is an extension method as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try extension class

```
using System;

public class PersonDTO
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public static class PersonDTOExtension {
    public static int GetName(this PersonDTO p) {
        // implement
        return p.Id;
    }
}

class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    var p = new PersonDTO();
    Console.WriteLine(p.GetName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `abstract` class and implement the method in it

```
public class PersonDTO: Parent
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

abstract class Parent {  
    public string GetName(string name) {  
         return name;  
    }  
}  

// 
static void Main() {
   var p = new PersonDTO();
   p.GetName(p.Name);
}
```